# Student T Distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics

**I have a data set of 500 rows and 1 column, in which there are human sizes.**

*I choose samples from this data set.*

I have 3 different samples, all 50 in size, but the first one has 80 different random variables, the second one has 40 different random variables, and the third one has different random variables.

```
sample(persons_Heights,size = 80) # sample_list_1
sample(persons_Heights,size = 40) # sample_list_2
sample(persons_Heights,size = 20) # sample_list_3
```

Then I computed the t value for each variable.

Here is the formula : (x¯(n) - µ) / (s(n)/sqrt(sample_size))

- x¯(n) = average of each sample in the list
- µ = Population Mean
- s(n) = standard deviation of each sample

I found the t-value for sample_list_1 --> t1

I found the t-value for sample_list_2 --> t2

I found the t-value for sample_list_3 --> t3

then I combined them in a single vector

```
all_T_Values <- c(t1,t2,t3)
```

Here is the all_T_Values

[image: all t values]

I would like to draw Student-T-Distribution for 3 samples.

And I want to see a shape like this

[image: Comparison of t Distribution]

I found a code on the internet that can draw the shape I want
Here:

```
x <- seq(-4, 4, length=100) 
hx <- dnorm(x)

degf <- c(1, 3, 8, 30)
colors <- c("red", "blue", "darkgreen", "gold", "black")
labels <- c("df=1", "df=3", "df=8", "df=30", "normal")

plot(x, hx, type="l", lty=2, xlab="x value",
     ylab="Density", main="Comparison of t Distributions")

for (i in 1:4){
  lines(x, dt(x,degf[i]), lwd=2, col=colors[i])
}

legend("topright", inset=.05, title="Distributions",
       labels, lwd=2, lty=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2), col=colors)
```

Here is my code :

```
t1;t2;t3

all_T_Values <- c(t1,t2,t3)
all_T_Values <- round(all_T_Values,3)
length(all_T_Values)
all_T_Values

hx <- dnorm(all_T_Values)
hx
length(hx)

degf <- c(20, 40, 80) # df = sample_size - 1
colors <- c("red", "blue", "darkgreen", "black")
labels <- c("df = 19", "df = 39", "df = 79", "normal")

plot(all_T_Values, hx, type = "l", lty = 2, xlab = "x value",
     ylab = "Density", main = "Comparison of t Distributions")

for(i in 1:3){
    lines(all_T_Values, dt(all_T_Values,degf[i]), lwd=2, col=colors[i])
}

legend("topright", inset=.05, title="Distributions",
       labels, lwd=2, lty=c(1, 1, 1, 2), col=colors)
```

**The Seq () method is used in the example on the internet. Instead I want to plot a t distribution using my "all_T_Values" values..**

I want to get this kind of image ==>

[image: Correct plot]

but I get an image like this ==>

[image: Wrong plot]

**I tried very hard on it but couldn't understand why. How can I fix this situation?**

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here.  The object you call `all_T_values` has 150 observations in it, but you should only have at most 140 and the formula that you propose should generate only 3.  One thing that you could do is to compare the density of your observations to a t-distribution with the same parameters (mean and variance).  Your observations even if you do a t-/z-transform will not necessarily have that distribution.  A bit more clarity about the ultimate goal and some example data would be useful.

Comment: You have three samples of sizes 80, 40, and 20. None of them are 50. Combining them gives you a single sample of 140, except that your listing includes 150. I suspect that you are trying to generate 50 samples each of three different sizes and then compare the means of those samples to a t distribution. Is that close to what you doing? If so, show us your code so far.

Comment: I changed the sample size to 16 and 6. Now there are 100 values ​​in the vector all_t_value. I get the result I want when I sort the values ​​on the X axis ascending. My new question will be like this. When I run the code, I see that the x axis is between -2 and 2, I want the range to be between -4 and 4. How do I do this?

Comment: See the manual page for `?plot.default` specifically the `xlim=` argument that lets you set your x-axis, e.g. `xlim=c(-4, 4)`.

Comment: Thanks for everyone.I got what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what intend to achieve, I suspect it is many things at once. Anyway I'll take this as a little challenge or exercise for myself.

I won't use any bodyheight measurements here, only simulated height *differences*.

If  you want to combine a histogram with a density plot, you can do this with `ggplot2` and `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
# generate vector of 500 draws from a t-distribution with 80 degrees of freedom.
# use R's builtin rt() function for this.
heightdiffs80 <- rt(n = 500, df = 80)

# for plotting, turn vector into tibble, a modern data frame. 
# call col1 "values".
samp80 <- tibble(values = heightdiffs80)

# preview
glimpse(samp80)

#Rows: 500
#Columns: 1
#$ values <dbl> 0.452752, -0.786840, -1.381138, -0.113225,…


theme_set(theme_bw()) # optional, white
# draw a plot with a layer of magic ..density.. column
# which ggplot always calculates to draw any histogram
ggplot(samp80, aes(values, ..density..)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, alpha = 0.2) + 
  geom_density(color = "blue", size=0.5)
```

[image: heightdiffs]

For an extra plot-layer
Calculate data for another layer of "theoretical" values :

```r
# in interval -4 to 4, get the values of the density function of the t distribution
# from  R's built-in dt() function
x <- seq(-4,4, 0.1)
dt80 <- dt(x = x, df = 80)
# turn it into a tibble, this time with colnames x and y
t80 <- tibble(x = x, y = dt80)
# preview
glimpse(t80)

# Rows: 81
# Columns: 2
# $ x <dbl> -4.0, -3.9, -3.8, -3.7, -3.6, -3.5, -3.4, -3.3,…
# $ y <dbl> 0.000247009, 0.000345186, 0.000479601, 0.000662…
```

Add  layer of "theoretical" values to plot

```r
ggplot(samp80, aes(values, ..density..)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, alpha = 0.2) + 
  geom_density(color = "blue", size=0.5) +
  # add an extra layer with the data from dt() function
  geom_line(data = t80, aes(x, y),  
            color = "dodgerblue", size=1) +
  geom_point(data = t80, aes(x, y),  
            color = "dodgerblue", size=1.2) +
  labs(title = "t-distribution, with 80 degrees of freedom",
       subtitle = "500 draws simulated, vs calculated (fat line)")
```

[image: t-distr]

Simply comment out the layers that you don't need.

Sorry for not adding a legend, I forgot how to do this, and I am out of time.